# how to parse javascript object with undefined as string in python

Tags: javascript, python, json, python-3.x

Im trying to scrape a website for the javscript objects it contains. Im trying to load them as python dictionary.
However, I can't just pass the javascript object in json.loads because it contains undefined as values. How can we load javascript object from strings to python dictionaries?

Comment: Try using some dedicated JavaScript parser, for example [`esprima`](https://pypi.org/project/esprima/).

Comment: Is it possible to convert those `undefined` to `null`?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf You could try replacing it, but i thought that might be dangerous? Also, they might not be the only differences between javascript objects and json.

Comment: @zwer i tried it and it seems it just makes things way unnecessarily complicated. Under the assumptions that the javascript object is basic and only contains, strings, lists, ints and nesting, is there an easier way?